# Print one column of data frame with row names

Tags: r, dataframe

Consider a data frame with custom row names:

```
> data <- data.frame(a=1:3,b=2:4,c=3:5,row.names=c("x","y","z"))
> data
  a b c
x 1 2 3
y 2 3 4
z 3 4 5
```

If I select **more than one column**, R prints them along with the row names:

```
> data[,c("a","c")]
  a c
x 1 3
y 2 4
z 3 5
```

But if I select **only one column**, R prints it as a simple vector, without the row names:

```
> data[,"c"]
[1] 3 4 5
```

My question is, how do I tell R to print **one column** in the same way it prints multiple columns, that is, **with the row names**?

Comment: @user1981275's answer works because when you're subsetting using [, "c"], R tries to simplify object class. Telling him not to "drop" it, preserves your data.frame class.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use the `drop` argument (see also `?'['`):

```
data[,"c", drop=FALSE]
```

gives you a `data.frame`

```
  c
x 3
y 4
z 5
```

Comment: This is similar to `subset(data,select="c")` and this generates a one-column dataframe. Do you konw how to get a named character vector instead ? (cc @RomanCheplyaka)

Comment: I could only think of  `apply(data[,"c", drop=FALSE], 1, c)` but maybe there is be a simpler solution.

Comment: Or if you really want a named character vector `apply(data[,"c", drop=FALSE], 1, as.character, c)
`

Comment: I know is long ago, but on the posts of @user1981275: for me `apply(data[,"c", drop=FALSE], 1, as.numeric)` works better, first I get problems with the c at the end and for this data example as.numeric seems to be better

Answer (score 6):

An even easier way is `data['c']`, which will result in the same output:

```
  c
x 3
y 4
z 5
```

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to data.frames, getting a column from matrices in R seem to retain their (row)names. One of the (many!) weird inconsistencies I find in R... To get a named vector one of these seems to work:

```
as.matrix(data['c'])[,1]
```

or

```
array(data['c'], dimnames=list(rownames(data)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, use select with column slicing:

```
data %>%
    select(1:2) %>%
    head
```